# General formula for the series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to find a general formula for the sequence $\{u_n\}$:
\begin{array}{c|c}
n&u_n\\
\hline
4&20\\
5&40\\
6&82  \\
7&172  \\
8&352  \\
9 &724  \\
10&1470  \\
11&2968  \\
12&5980  \\
13&12020\\
\end{array}

A lower bound on these values is $5\cdot2^{n-2}$.

Comment: Why do you think there is a formula?  What else do you know about the sequence?  Where does it come from?

Comment: No hits in the OEIS, by the way.

Comment: Apparently, the upper bound is $6\cdot2^{n-2}$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael These are the numbers generated from my project. Where I am generating the number of subproblems executed for a query in worst case. I strongly believe there has to be some formula behind this, these numbers have been generated using the bruteforce code.

Comment: @GouravKumar Is it possible for you to paste the code here? Maybe we can see some pattern.

Comment: You might consider contributing this to the [OEIS](https://oeis.org) (with details, of course).